# Basic Authentication with Twitter and Facebook

Tags: twitter, facebook-c#-sdk, dotnetopenauth, twitter-oauth

Is there a way to authenticate to Facebook / Twitter using basic authentication? the application I am working on requires posting to those two sites without the need to open the oAuth Dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, thank goodness.

Basic authentication requires that you take the user's password, which is a secret between them and Twitter/Facebook.  You shouldn't be asking for it.

If your app is physically unable to display the dialog, OAuth 2.0 (not available on Twitter) offers a way (last I checked) for an independent web browser on another computer to perform the OAuth authorization process to your app running on some limited device.

Comment: Actually, my application needs to post to Twitter / Facebook using a fixed username and password. That's why I needed this service. I will end up logging in once to the accounts so that the app doesnt need to authenticate every time, unless there is a smarter way of doing it.

Comment: Ah, when you say "fixed username and password" do you mean one that you as a programmer own?  If so you can probably do what you need by visiting https://dev.twitter.com/apps, registering your OAuth app, then using the "access token" and "access token secrets" at the bottom of the web page as the hard coded values in your app.  It's still OAuth though -- not basic auth.

Comment: Does the same hold true with Facebook?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know if Facebook offers a similar access token.  But they use OAuth 2 instead of OAuth 1, so when you're looking around, just know there won't be an access token secret -- just a long access token.

Answer (score 2):

Both [twitter](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq) & [facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) don't support basic auth.